# Why I am getting 415 for this request

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a controller,

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ResponsesController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public void Data([FromBody] MyModel value)
    {
        var temp = value;
    }
}

[JsonObject]
[Serializable]
public class MyModel
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

and I am posting to it like this using chrome developer console,

```
function post_to_url(path, params, method) {
    method = method || "post";

    var form = document.createElement("form");

    //Move the submit function to another variable
    //so that it doesn't get overwritten.
    form._submit_function_ = form.submit;

    form.setAttribute("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
    form.setAttribute("method", method);
    form.setAttribute("action", path);

    for(var key in params) {
        var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
        hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

        form.appendChild(hiddenField);
    }

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form._submit_function_(); //Call the renamed function.
}
var j = {"Url":"hello"};
post_to_url("http://localhost:63984/api/responses", j );
```

Error I am getting is 415 but I am not sure what is wrong, I actually want to receive myModel[]

Comment: What does the raw HTTP look like? This is normally caused by an invalid HTTP header.

Comment: First thing i notice is that you have to specify route like :
`[HttpGet("All")]`
or 
`[HttpPost("All")]` 
no matter actually depends of the action you expect.
You can use this syntax as well
`[HttpPost]
 [Route("All")]` 

both are valid syntax

Comment: Why aren't you using AJAX here?

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type#Content-Type_in_HTML_forms)

> In a POST request, resulting from an HTML form submission, the Content-Type of the request is specified by the enctype attribute on the  element.

You should remove the `form.setAttribute("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf8")` from your `post_to_url`. If you're going to submit your data that way, you may have to configure your service to accept url-encoded form data instead. It may work out of the box for something this simple though.

Answer (score 0):

415 indicates "Unsupported media". In your case you set your content-type to JSON but you are not really posting JSON, you are posting a hidden field with name="Url" and value="hello".